# Add Image over another image and save it

Tags: reactjs, image-processing, cloudinary

I am working on a react project in which we generate new images by fitting uploaded image in a tv screen, or laptop screen or mobile screen. So what I want is a way in which I can place the uploaded image into this below image[image]

In the black tv screen I want the uploaded image to fit and below there will be download option to download the uploaded image.

I searched for that and came across cloudinary react library. So I wrote this code to somehow fit an image inside this image but I can't seem to find any way to download that image.

If you have any idea of doing this please share with me.
Thank You in advance

Comment: `<a href="<upload image url>" download />` are you looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay images on other images without having to use a particular Cloudinary SDK, as outlined here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#adding_image_overlays

You can then place them more specifically using x and y coordinates in the URL as outlined here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#placing_overlays

Once you have generated an image with the overlay positioned correctly (and with any other transformations you may wish to process), you can download the generated image as normal.